# Turn animation CSS backwards

Tags: html, css, animation

On my little testing html page, I have 4 elements. These elements play a CSS animation when hovered over, but I would like the animation to go reverse when the user stops hovering over them.

```
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
```

didn't work. My current code is as follows:

```
<style>

div:hover{
-webkit-animation: animationFrames ease 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/ 
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
0% {

opacity:1;
-webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
}
20% {
-webkit-transform:  rotate(60deg) ;

}
40% {
-webkit-transform:  rotate(40deg) ;

}
60% {
-webkit-transform:  rotate(54deg) ;
}
80% {
-webkit-transform:  rotate(42deg) ;

}
100% {

opacity:1;
-webkit-transform:  rotate(46deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
}
}

.testje1
{
background: black;
width:48px;
height:20px;

position:absolute;
left:200px;
top:200px;
}

.testje2
{
background: black;
width:48px;
height:20px;


position:absolute;
left:300px;
top:200px;
}

.testje3
{
background: black;
width:48px;
height:20px;


position:absolute;
left:400px;
top:200px;
}

.testje4
{
background: black;
width:48px;
height:20px;

position:absolute;
left:500px;
top:200px;
}

p
{
position:absolute;
top:-14;
left:2;
color:white;
}
</style>

<a href="http://www.redrumbureau.com" target="_blank" >
<div class="testje1"><p>home</p></div>
</a>

<a href="http://www.redrumbureau.com/work" target="_blank">
<div class="testje2"><p>home</p></div>
</a>

<a href="http://www.redrumbureau.com/clients" target="_blank">
<div class="testje3"><p>clients</p></div>
</a>

<a href="http://www.redrumbureau.com/about" target="_blank">
<div class="testje4"><p>about</p></div>
</a>
```

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `animation-direction:reverse;`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't formulate my question correctly. I'm going to edit it right now.

Comment: Edit done a little while ago, but forgot to mention. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`reverse`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-direction.asp) to make the animation go "backwards":

```
-webkit-animation-direction:reverse;
```

Here's a nice detailed tutorial on [keyframes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) by CSS tricks if you'd like to learn more about the options available to you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't formulate my question correctly. I'm going to edit it right now.